# Why does Python's GIL enforce strict ordering of processing?

Tags: python, multithreading, python-3.x, python-multithreading, gil

```
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor, as_completed

def main():
    with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=16) as producersPool:
        for i in [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0]:
            producersPool.submit((lambda i : print(i))(i))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Running with python3:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
0
```

Always the same.

Now I'd like you to get me right - I don't necessarily wish for those tasks to be reordered, but I'm just wondering why does the ordering *happen at all*? I mean, one could expect to get things done in deterministic way inside one thread, but the strict queueing of the threads seems a bit odd to me.

Anyway, how do I get the real concurrency in Python 3? (Jython and IronPython support only 2.x, as far as I know).

Comment: Your example contains an important error: you're actually _calling_ the lambda and only passing the _result_ (which is always None) to `submit`. The observed behaviour has nothing to do with the ThreadPool. You probably wanted to write `(lambda i: (lambda: print(i)))(i)` instead.

Comment: @l4mpi, yes, I already noticed it and already hit myself in the face. I edited the code to `producersPool.submit(sleepy, i)` and it runs as expected, i.e. is a rather unpredicted fashion. Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All jobs are executed *before* they are submitted, and none of them do more than write to an output stream. You submit the *result* of calling each `lambda`.

Even if you used:

```
producersPool.submit(lambda i: print(i), (i,))
```

there is not *enough* in each thread to be preempted by another thread, so they all complete before any other thread can but in.

Comment: Ah, I see. Well, I added `sleep(5)` and it seems to print the list in a truly random way now. Thank you.

Comment: The actual problem in the example is that the printing happens in the main thread, and OP never submits anything other than `None` to the thread pool...

Comment: See my comment for @l4mpi (lambdas look a little raggedy here IMO, so I made a function).

Answer (score 2):

to answer the second part of your question:

> "how do I get the real concurrency in Python 3?"

you can use the [multiprocessing](http://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html) module:

> "multiprocessing is a package that supports spawning processes using
>   an API similar to the threading module. The multiprocessing package
>   offers both local and remote concurrency, effectively side-stepping
>   the Global Interpreter Lock by using subprocesses instead of threads."

Since your example used `ThreadPoolExecutor` from `concurrent.futures`, have a look at [`ProcessPoolExecutor`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#processpoolexecutor) in the same package.  It is similar to `ThreadPoolExecutor`, but uses processes (instead of threads), so it is not hampered by the GIL.

Comment: Yeah, I saw it, but just didn't think about the possibility. That's great, I'm sorry I can't accept two answers at once (I shouldn't have asked two at once first of all:) )